# Map are re-rendering all my components that already is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a upload component, I have cards that will be rendered with images and with those images, inputs.
But when I was rendering(as I show in the console log below), the map are rendering all the 8 images, and then he just start again, and then I got a loop.

```
index.js?64f4:41 []
index.js?64f4:41 []
index.js?64f4:41 (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 0
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 1
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 2
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 3
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 4
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 5
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 6
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 7
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 8
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 0
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 1
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 2
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 3
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 4
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 5
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 6
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 7
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 8
index.js?64f4:41 (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 0
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 1
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 2
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 3
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 4
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 5
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 6
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 7
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 8
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 0
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 1
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 2
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 3
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 4
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 5
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 5
index.js?0370:1 Uncaught DOMException: The source image cannot be decoded.
g @ index.js?0370:1
CardForm @ index.js?44e2:53
CardForm @ react-hot-loader.development.js?c2cb:827
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:15590
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:18021
updateSimpleMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:17880
updateMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:17757
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:20041
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:310
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:359
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:421
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:25127
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23859
workLoopConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23845
renderRootConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23802
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23035
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js?1911:595
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js?1911:550
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js?1911:162
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 6
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 7
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 8
index.js?64f4:41 (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 0
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 1
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 2
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 3
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 4
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 5
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 6
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 7
index.js?64f4:107 inside map of pictures 8
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 0
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 1
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 2
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 3
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 4
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 5
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 5
index.js?0370:1 Uncaught DOMException: The source image cannot be decoded.
g @ index.js?0370:1
CardForm @ index.js?44e2:53
CardForm @ react-hot-loader.development.js?c2cb:827
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:15590
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:18021
updateSimpleMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:17880
updateMemoComponent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:17757
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:20041
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:310
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:359
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:421
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:25127
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23859
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23779
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23738
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:23062
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js?1911:595
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js?1911:550
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js?1911:162
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 6
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 7
index.js?44e2:57 inside cardForm 8
index.js?2c06:35 DOMException: The source image cannot be decoded. {componentStack: "↵    at CardForm (webpack-internal:///./node_modul…ader/dist/react-hot-loader.development.js:827:20)"}
```

This is my map:

```
{pictures.map((picture, index) => {
                console.log('inside map of pictures', index)
                return (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <Suspense fallback={<Spinner size="5rem" />}>
                      <Card
                        key={index}
                        identifierOfPicture={picture.identifier}
                        states={states}
                        filesList={filesList}
                        setFiles={setFiles}
                        index={index}
                        picture={picture.urlImage}
                        removeImage={removeImage}
                        duplicateImage={duplicateImage}
                        arrayOfInputs={inputs(states, picture.identifier, dispatch, defaultQuantityValue, device, isSubmitting)}
                        pictures={pictures}
                        setPictures={setPictures}
                        dispatch={dispatch}
                        uuid={uuid}
                        thumbPhoto={thumbPhoto}
                        setThumbPhoto={setThumbPhoto}
                      />
                    </Suspense>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
```

The component is exported as memo(UploadImages), and the cardForm too!
Someone have some ideas to try?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I see that you are passing states to your map, and updating those states may rerender the whole component.

Comment: Yes! But the other times that I was working with this, the React.memo sorted out!

Comment: Did any state variables change in the `UploadImages` component in between the loops?